# How significant were government-linked enterprises as a source of revenue for the United States between 1790 and 1846?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, government, business-history, public-finance

What proportion of US government (federal,state,local) revenue came from profits or debt issuance of government-linked enterprises between 1790 and 1846?

I chose 1846 as the breakpoint because of the [Walker Tariff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walker_tariff); feel free to critique that choice.

Related questions: [What were the sources of US government revenue from 1790 to 1846?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61304/what-were-the-sources-of-us-government-revenue-from-1790-to-1846)

**Background:**

I have found sources sufficient to establish that government-linked enterprises were significant; these are listed below. However, I have not found enough to give me an idea of the magnitude.

1. (h/t to [Brian Z](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/3011/brian-z)) [This paper](https://www.everycrsreport.com/files/20060925_RL33665_4a8c6781ce519caa3e6b82f95c269f73021c5fdf.pdf) ("CRS Report") attempts to break down overall federal revenue; since it purports to be comprehensive, it can potentially rule out a lot of things. For the period prior to 1863, it says that excise (up to ~1816) and customs (after ~1816), along with public land sales, contributed most of the federal revenue. [This paper](http://econweb.umd.edu/%7Ewallis/MyPapers/Wallis_GovtFinance_JEP_2000.pdf), in turn (table 1 on p6), helps estimate the percentage of US revenue that went to the federal government versus state versus local. However, I have not done the necessary work to determine whether I can reasonably "glue together" these sources. I'm also not certain that "CRS Report" intends to include things like tolls in its accounting.
2. [This survey ("Wallis 1")](http://econweb.umd.edu/%7Ewallis/MyPapers/Wallis_GovtFinance_JEP_2000.pdf) motivates the question (p3 of the pdf) by identifying infrastructure investment as an important source of government income for the period 1790 and 1842. It also gives a partial indirect answer by estimating the relative share of property taxes for state governments from 1835 through the end of my period (p8 of the pdf).
3. [This paper](https://www.nber.org/papers/h0097.pdf) ("GWS") goes into more detail for individual states toward the end of my period and takes a close look at financing. I have not assimilated it yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What proportion of US government revenue was federal/state/local/other, for various periods between 1790 and 1846?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/what-proportion-of-us-government-revenue-was-federal-state-local-other-for-vari)

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens Thanks! it's related but not quite the same. But depending on the answers, one might work to answer the other. I originally had a long multi-part question but split it up based on a suggestion in the comments. This question and the linked question are some of the resulting questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What proportion of US government revenue came from non-tax-seeming sources, for various periods between 1790 and 1846?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61309/what-proportion-of-us-government-revenue-came-from-non-tax-seeming-sources-for)

Comment: @Carey Gregory Thanks, good question! It might. I would consider profits of government-linked enterprises to be a subset of non-tax-seeming sources, and I expect most people to agree. Any comprehensive answer to your linked question would probably also end up answering this question. However, I don't necessarily expect a comprehensive answer to the linked question and I want to direct particular attention to government-linked enterprises. The obvious alternative would be for me to call out government-linked enterprises in the linked question. Should I do that?

Comment: @Carey Gregory The reason why I have not already done so is this: I fear that calling out government-linked enterprises in the question you linked above will result in a question that is too unfocused or broad.